# How to force visual studio to generate properties using lower case type (i.g., string instead of String)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I am trying to set `C#` style rule in `.editorconfig` file in Visual Studio 2022, so it will always generate the code style that I would use in my project.

Currently, VS generates properties or fields using `String` and `Int32` instead of `string` and `int`. Although, I am aware that `string` is an alias of `String`, I would like to use `string` and `int` instead when defining types.

However, when trying to access static methods like [String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) I want to use `String` instead of `string`. So the style would look like this

```
public class Test
{
    // use lowercase here (string not String)
    private string _name;

    // use lowercase here (string not String)
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Test(string name)
    {
        // use uppercase here (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) not string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new Exception("...");
        }

        _name = name;
    }
}
```

What rules can I add to the `.editorconfig` file to allow Visual Studio 2022 to follow the above style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0049)

When setting `dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members` to `true` VS will prefer the language keyword for local variables, method parameters, and class members.

When setting `dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access` to `false` VS will prefer the framework classes.

In short, you need to add this to the `.editorconfig` file

```
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = false
```

Optionally, you can enforce the code style in your project either by using `warning` of `error`. `warning` will show you an a curly line under the non-compliant type, while `error` force the compiler to fail.

Here is an example of how to enforce the style using `warning`

```
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true : warning
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = false : warning
```