# C# (Visual Studio IDE / VSCode) - how to hide .NET types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022, omnisharp

When I begin to write type `Visual Studio IDE` and `VSCode` show not only the C# types but `.Net` types also (i.e: int - Int16, byte - Byte):

[image]

Is it possible to hide `.Net` type intelliSense?

Comment: I see no reason why anyone would take the trouble to implement such a feature, because it would mean blacklisting *specific* types (`Int16` because `short` exists, but not `Int16Converter`). It's even worse for `IntPtr` -- should it be hidden because C# 11 has `nint`? (Probably not because the intended semantics are often different, but it shows the arbitrariness.)

Comment: Hello, is there any update in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer could help you: [How to force visual studio to generate properties using lower case type (i.g., string instead of String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094071/how-to-force-visual-studio-to-generate-properties-using-lower-case-type-i-g-s)

But it's just an Alias:

> In the preceding tables, each C# type keyword from the left column (except dynamic) **is an alias for the corresponding .NET type**. They are interchangeable.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types)

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliSense completion lists in C# contain tokens from List Members, Complete Word, and more.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-intellisense?view=vs-2022#filtered-completion-lists

In the C# section of the visual studio IDE, I didn't find any changes to the
IntelliSense to hide one of the configurations. If you want to hide the .Net type, you can only hide IntelliSense.

Effect：
[image]

[image]

You can also choose not to show the structure when writing the type, but you need to select it manually after writing.

[image]